# ViewsJSON module not working with Google Store Locator

Tags: 7, google-maps

I was wondering if anyone came with a solution for this. The Google Store Locator module is not working with ViewsJSON module. There seems to be an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357027)

I've installed the ViewJSON Alpha 4 and applied the patch but it doesn't work on my end.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working with version 7.x-1.0-alpha2 of module GeoJSON.

Please see my question and my own answer at [Localize nearest store to a zip code in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169749/localize-nearest-store-to-a-zip-code-in-drupal-7)

Comment: I've tried the 7.x-1.0-alpha2, 7.x-1.0-alpha3, 7.x-1.0-alpha4, 7.x-1.0-alpha5 and it didn't work. However when I tried on a new install, 7.x-1.0-alpha2 did work. It seems I got an issue with my installation.

Comment: I also had problems and switched off Google Store Locator and GeoJson modules, uninstalled them, and even deleted the folders, later I re-installed with the version I comment. You can check in Status report if you have any missing library or module. I thought it was a conflict among different modules but it seems to affect just to ViewsJSON and GSL modules interaction and when going back to alpha2 version, it just works perfectly. I did read about the version in the module issues page and also verified from the date of a video tutorial in which I saw it working perfectly.