# Localize nearest store to a zip code in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, google-maps

I just want to let the user enter a ZIP code, and return the nearest store from the database. I have read and I am trying Module Location + Gmap (for visual input), but I think that this module stores all data in a database. Wouldn't it be more reliable to go through a service like Google GeoCode or something? I would appreciate insights from people who has managed this problem before, as somehow I am confused with many different options available in the contributed modules.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use set [proxmity](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation_proximity) in views and Dependencies modules are
[Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation), [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).[image]

Comment: I have managed to get it work, but the final result is rather poor. I mean, you can search by Postal code or by lat/long, but not, for example, by entering a full text addreess. CMS like Prestashop have this in the core. I have been trying to see if there are other combinations of modules but doesn't seem to exist anything which could pre-feed the exposed filter or something. Maybe using OpenLayers module?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get working a version with modules Location + GMap, which was very primitive, because it only used ZIP code, and later I found the fantastic Google Store Locator module, which does exactly what I needed, finding the GPS coordinates for any human readable text address and displaying the stores (or points) in the map.

The only caveat is that for a correct install, I needed to use an old version of module GeoJSON (7.x-1.0-alpha2) and I also needed to install the following library and module, respectively (I didn't find in the documentation, but in the Status report page): markerclusterer library and Contextual Range Filter module.